# getting Python set up in Sublime 2 with Windows 7-64bit

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I tried quite a few things Stack overflow and various blogs have suggested in setting Python path, but whenever I hit Ctrl + B, it says "Building" and nothing happens.

Sublime 2 64bit correctly installed
Python 3.3 and 2.7 installed
Windows 7 64bit SP1 installed

1. Python.sublime-build path manually set to python33/python.exe
2. Path variable in system setting: added ;C:\Python33;
3. Copied said Python.sublime-build from Packages/Python to Packages/user

What else can I try?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the full contents of your `Python.sublime-build` file (not `Sublime.python-build`...). Also, please describe what *"it doesn't really work for me"* means. Do you get any errors? Does a build panel open at the bottom of the Sublime window? Are you getting any tracebacks? Please add all these details to your question so we may assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unless you know exactly what you're doing, if you want to edit any `.sublime-build` files, you should copy them to your `Packages/User` directory and rename them. This maintains the original file in case you mess something up and want to look at the original again, and maintains expected behavior in case you have problems with something in the future.

I have two Python 3 [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) on my Windows system. One is a simple copy of `Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build`, with the direct path to the Python 3.3 binary coded in:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["c:/Python33/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

The second is more complex. Sublime does not allow you to accept interactive input (Python 2's `raw_input()` and Py3's `input()`, Ruby's `gets`, etc.), and it also doesn't allow you to launch GUIs. If you have a program that does one or more of these things, you need to run it from the command prompt. This build system does that, and leaves the command prompt window open so you can examine output, tracebacks, etc.

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/python27/python.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

Of course, you could easily change the path to Python 3.3 if you wished.

Follow the link above to the build systems docs (make sure you check out the "Reference" link at the bottom) at [docs.sublimetext.info](http://docs.sublimetext.info), which is the home of the "official unofficial" Sublime Text documentation. While the ["official" docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/) have some good stuff, it is rather incomplete, so the unofficial ones were created to comprehensively document the program. If you look around there, you should be able to find answers to many of your questions.